# get image src if there is more then image src just get one image src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get image src using jquery like this:

HTML

```
<div class="post_container"> 
   <img src="http://imageurl.com">
</div>
<div class="appendedimageContainer"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var imageSrc = $('.post_container img').attr('src');
$(".appendedimageContainer").append('<div class="appended"><img src="'+imageSrc+'"></div>');
```

The code above works in a healthy way, but the question I would like to ask is here. If the pictures are more than one I want them not to be append. I just want to get one of them append.

For example if a situation as follows:

```
<div class="post_container"> 
   <img src="http://imageurl1.com">
   <img src="http://imageurl2.com">
   <img src="http://imageurl3.com">
   <img src="http://imageurl4.com">
</div>
<div class="appendedimageContainer"></div>
```

Just let one of them get a image url and ignore other image src. Can you help How can I do this?

Comment: _Just let one of them get a image url_ Still your code will work. However you can be sure using `$('.post_container img:first').attr('src')` or `$('.post_container img:last').attr('src')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nth-child selector to obtain your desired image, e.g.

```
var imageSrc = $('.post_container img:nth-child(0)').attr('src');
```

Comment: `$('.post_container img')[0]` return element not jquery object that you trying to use `.attr()` after it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use first() to get the first element :-

```
var imageSrc = $('.post_container img').first().attr('src');
```